# Is there a way to alternate between tables in a Sequelize Schema using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a database with very similar tables. `table1` and `table2` has the same columns and use the same logic in my API (nodejs 8).

I want to share one Schema in the two tables. And depending on the request's headers (I will declare a global variable) I want to alternate and use one or another table.

My `table1` schema:

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

const Table1 = global.sequelize.define('table1', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.BIGINT(20)
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  username: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
})

module.exports = Table1
```

So when I query in the code I can use always the same schema - example: `Table.findAll({})` -, and I never have to use ifs or ternary to specify which table I want

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the reason behind doing that? For example why not having one table and an extra column to flag the row based on the request headers?

Comment: In other projects, these same tables will be used in different ways. And I want to make sure that any handler (existent or new) in this API doesn't have to know which table to use, for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

The premise is unusual.  I don't think there is a way to change the table name on the fly (and probably there should **not** be, as models should be const).  You can make it work by defining both tables:

Here is models/Table:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

const setOfColumns = {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.BIGINT(20)
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  username: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
};

const Table1 = global.sequelize.define('table1', setOfColumns );
const Table2 = global.sequelize.define('table2', setOfColumns );

module.exports = {Table1, Table2}
```

You said:

> depending on the request's headers (I will declare a global variable)
>   I want to alternate and use one or another table.

which IMHO is more or less the same as an IF or ternary.  Here's how the controller might look:

```
const tables  = require('../models/Table');
...
let TableModel = req.params.whichTable === '1' ? tables.Table1 : tables.Table2;

TableModel.findAll()..
```

HTH.